# How to pass a string parameter from angular UI to node.js backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am trying to pass a string value from angular UI to node.js backend api which then searches in mongodb using the passed string value as below.

I try to take the input in `enteredValue` and pass it on to `http.get` call as `params:this.enteredValue` and to node.js as `req.params`,as you can see below if I hardcode the string value for "orgChange",it works fine but somehow passing params is not working and throwing errors?any guidance on how to fix this?

html:

```
<textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
<hr>
<button (click)="get_change_lifecycle_data()">Search</button>

<p>{{newPost | json }}</p>
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-input',
  templateUrl: './change-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-input.component.css']
})


export class ChangeInputComponent  {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

enteredValue : any;
newPost : any;
get_change_lifecycle_data(){
     this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/change_life_cycle2',{params:this.enteredValue}).subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response);
      this.newPost = response
      });
}

}
```

node.js

hardcode the string value for "orgChange",it works fine

```
app.get("/api/change_life_cycle", (req, res, next) => {
 Change_life_cycle.find({ orgChange: "51918661" }).then(documents => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
      posts: documents
    });
  });
});
```

API with req.params

```
   app.get("/api/change_life_cycle2", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
     Change_life_cycle.find({ orgChange: req.params }).then(documents => {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
    });
```

Error:--

```
(node:75156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{}" at path "orgChange" for model "change_life_cycle"
    at new CastError (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
    at SchemaString.cast (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/string.js:553:11)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:948:12)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType._castForQuery (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1362:15)
    at SchemaString.castForQuery (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/string.js:609:15)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1331:15)
    at cast (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:252:34)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4576:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1783:10)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1810:8)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _find] (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:16:8)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/username/Downloads/mongodb-03-finished/node_modules/kareem/index.js:369:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:75156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:75156) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using `HttpParams`:

```
get_change_lifecycle_data(){
     const params = new HttpParams().set('params', this.enteredValue);
     this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/change_life_cycle2',{params})
     .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.newPost = response
      });
}
```

and in `node` use `req.query` to access params:

```
   app.get("/api/change_life_cycle2", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
     Change_life_cycle.find({ orgChange: req.query.params }).then(documents => {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: this throws error `HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/change_life_cycle2?params=51918661", ok: false, …}`

Comment: @user2125827 Can u check the spelling etc, `404` is about URL not found. `/api/change_life_cycle2`

Comment: you are right,there was a typo :-) ,it works now,thanks much

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** There are three ways to get parameters to express:

1. req.query --> this case, query parameters
2. req.body --> post request body payload
3. req.params --> /:someParam in url params

so i missed it :) it should be req.query.searchKey.

Change the query to like this: u need to pass different params with different names:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/change_life_cycle2', 
  {
    params:{
    searchKey: this.enteredValue
    }
  }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.newPost = response
});
```

In API side read the params in the request like this:

```
app.get("/api/change_life_cycle2", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
     Change_life_cycle.find({ orgChange: req.query.searchKey }).then(documents => {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: `  console.log(req.params.searchKey)` shows as `undefined` in the `app.get` call,looks like the searchKey param is not reaching the node.js `app.get` call

Comment: see edit, it should be rew.query.searchKey, I apologise